# Angular 2 Cannot read property 'glob' of null Error

Tags: angular

I am trying using angular cli and new angular2 project but error 
[image: Error İmage]

in Php Storm error is : You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project

Comment: Not sure why you're seeing the error in the attached image. But the error "You cannot use the new command inside an angular cli project", you cant create a new app using 'ng new proj' while in a directory that already has an app generated by the cli. You might want to try to uninstall the cli and reinstall it.

Comment: I am try the cli uninstall but again Cannon read property glob error

Comment: Hey, i faced the same issue but i resolved it by removing all angular-cli.json files which were above my project folder. In your case check the C:\ folder for angular-cli.json files and remove them (also look for hidden files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the directory find file like c:/users/username/angular*.json

delete it, then run again.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, I had run ng unit in system root directory by mistake. Once I had delete all the angular-cli files it was working

What I had done to resolve on windows-7 and windows-10 system.

1. Open cmd.
2. Run dir. (in Linux or mac its ls).
3. If you find angular-cli files just delete.

And it's work for me.

It is mainly duplicate of angular-cli inside the directory.

Answer (score 0):

In mac is the same in the folder `/users/{user}/`

```
remove -rf .angular-cli.json
```

Answer (score 0):

check if there is any hidden .angular-cli.json or angular-cli.json in your users/system-name folder, and check duplicates in your project.
 Worked for me.